# Swiftui - TextField with optional observedObject

Tags: swiftui, textfield, option-type, observedobject

Here I have view with a textfield that reads off an ObservedObject. The Observed object has a property called "user" that is of optional type "NewUser?". When I try to unwrap the "NewUser" to retrieve its username for the textfied I get an error saying that I must still unwrap it.

#### The Errors

#### NewUser Model

```
struct NewUser: {
    var id: UUID?
    var username: String
}
```

#### Observed Object

```
class HTTPUserClient: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user: NewUser? //a user struct with a non optional 
    //function and stuff ommitted
}
```

#### View

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestUserEditor: View {
    @ObservedObject var userClient:HTTPUserClient
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("required", text: $userClient.user!.username)   
    } 
}
```

#### The errors

IF I use the above code I get the following error

```
Value of optional type 'NewUser?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'firstName' of wrapped base type 'NewUser'
```

but if I fix it by adding a "!", force unwrapping the user, I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to get rid of the optional by adding a static `example` as a placeholder.

```
struct NewUser {
    var id: UUID?
    var username: String

    static let example = NewUser(id: nil, username: "")
}
```

and declare `user`

```
@Published var user = NewUser.example
```